# Jquery colorbox popup lost his alignment in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox, internet-explorer-9

I am using the Jquery colorbox pop ups they work superbly in all browsers except in IE9: they lost his position, height and width when they open. Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: I`m guessing its a different interpretation of the CSS in IE9. Can you post the code?

Comment: share design link opens a popup its not working properly in IE9

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem went away with NOT using mootools.js on the same page where I used colorbox. So I guess mootools.js and colorbox together don't work in IE9.

Answer (score -1):

In my case (magento) it was a problem with other scripts (using prototype). Removing prototype library made colorbox working fine also in IE9. Trying `jQuery.noConflict();` didn't help to made scripts work together. I've added compatibility meta tag, to force compatibility mode in IE9 with IE8.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```